# Magic system for teleportation without colonization

Tags: balancing-magic-systems, teleportation

I am looking for a magic setting that supports a role playing campaign we are trying to start. The game wants to focus on potentially-peaceful exploration of different pre-modern cultures. I am looking for a flavourful magic system that could support our play style.

- A small group of people, possibly with special talents or expertise (i.e. the player characters) should be able to travel to faraway places in negligible time, with no or little much contact to the geography inbetween.
- The travel magic makes colonization as difficult as possible: By contrast, it does not allow an invading army to travel to a rich place to enforce a regular tribute and pressures like that.
- The travel system is part of a more general system of magic with rules that can be reasoned about.
- Aside from the travels, the setting is so low-magic that several of Earth's pre-modern societies could exist in the setting with little or no adaptation.
- Ideally, travelling like this tends to send people to wilderness, but the sending has to happen from civilization, so there is both some scope for overland travel adventures and a reason to cooperate with the locals at the destination.

I am considering some kind of spirit world through which the player characters can travel (and their expertise is rare), maybe with a more metaphorical geography, or a kind of built structure that requires whatever “mystic energy” a community can muster for a week to send everyone on the inside to a partially-defined location.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Right now while there's a decent amount of information in this post, it's not really clear what exactly your asking for. Stack isn't really a general discussion site but a Q&A fourm

Comment: I think that achieving your goal has little to do with the mechanism of the transport and more to do with the cost. Make the cost high enough, and nobody can afford to send more than a couple people.

Comment: There's a technical problem here. You say you don't want colonization and don't want armies to collect tributes? Traditionally though, a tax collector was a single person. You don't need an army to collect tributes. You just need to convince the people paying that bad things will happen if they don't. And being able to spontaneously appear is a **really** good way of convincing a people of that.

Comment: Even if we talk numbers - in NZ, pre colonization Hapu (sub-tribes) ranged between 50-150 people - if you teleport in, with superior weaponary - your small party (5-10 people) could be sufficient to take on/take out an entire Hapu. If you have say longbows and they don't or plate armour and they don't.

Comment: Um... I'm tempted to vote to close, but I'm not sure why. I don't think "magic systems" are like books on a shelf that you can pick and choose between. Yes, there are well-defined 3rd party/commercial magic systems, but we don't answer 3rd party/commercial world questions. And I've never seen them advertised for use by others like the Unreal 3D Engine is for video games. I therefore think that aspect ofyour question is unanswerable. On the other hand, *creating an entire magic system to solve your problem* is very much a violation of the Book Rule. So, do you have a *specific* problem?

Comment: A little bit to broad of a question in my opinion. Maybe you should clarify what exactly you want.

Comment: I'm okay with this question getting closed for being to broad/unclear. It was difficult to phrase and I do see that it still has several problems, so please go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

There is not much of a system, it is a genetic neurological predisposition.

Some, very, very, very rare people can teleport. The reasons why are not clear, but the gist of it is that they are neurodivergent in a specific narrow way that lets them intuitively understand that the true topology of reality is NOT the same as its physical geography. They basically are able to move along a different dimensional axis than just the 1,2 and 3, because they are able to perceive it properly.

The problem is, nobody else can perceive the extra axis, so their mind substitutes the time-axis instead. Sure, the Mover can take another person and teleport them. This is actually as easy as teleporting any other heavy load. The problem is, the mind of the passenger will experience the travel along the extra axis as travel along the time axis, with the subjective time of travel being about equal to the time it would take to freefall the same distance, and the experience being a total, absolute, null-epistemology sensory deprivation (except for the passage of subjective time). The passenger would feel nothing, see nothing (not see black. See **NOTHING**.). They would no longer experience the boundary between their mind and the rest of reality, or between the parts of their mind itself. IF the trip is short they might manage to keep experiencing their Self, but even that would quickly erode to gibberish, then void. It is kind of the evil opposite of the Buddhist Nirvana.

The effect is that any passenger moved more than about 100 miles would arrive in a state of stupefied shock. Any distance longer than about 200 miles, and the passenger would likely remain catatonic for weeks, possibly remain incurably insane. At 500+ miles of travel? Forget it. The Passenger would arrive in braindead coma, or have a violent seizure at arrival and die.

In theory, teleporting a passenger a few miles is "harmless", but pretty much everyone who experienced it even once say it was the worst torture they ever experienced, worse they could even *imagine*, and would rather be killed than do it again.

For an added cruel twist: the easiest method to find new Movers is for established Movers to teleport quirky/autistic/weird children and see which ones come out fine, and without extreme PTSD.

Same problem happens when the Movers try to teleport most animals. Anything more complex than an insect goes crazy.

In theory, the passenger could be sedated for the trip, but the amount and potency of sedatives needed to put them under completely and not experience Nothingness is going to kill them in most cases (ex: the amount of morphine needed for one to sleep through the trip is greater than the amount that an ordinary person can take and survive).

As such, Movers are only used as explorers, messengers and diplomats. There is no possibility for them to use their power for colonization, and they cannot move enough weight to be used for trade.

Also, the horrors associated with being teleported by a Mover makes them scary and mistrusted by most. To some superstitious or religious folk, the Movers are just evil witches who serve the Void Beyond Worlds.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with something of a more shamanic bent, since the question mentioned a spirit world as a possibility.

**Bargaining in Good Spirit**

In addition to a Spirit World alongside the real one, there are also spirits that can be negotiated with for favours when needed.  The more significant a place is, the stronger the spirit generally.  Likewise, the stronger the effect negotiated, the more power is required to perform it.

Outright teleporting takes a lot of power due to the way it bends the physical world -- taking the distance between here and there and putting it behind the party.  Most know it's generally better to bargain for passage through a particular path in the spirit world.  It's safer and disrupts the worlds less.

As to why a teleport would need to start from a town?  Well, the primary spirits of settlements were born from our desire and/or need to expand and settle.  The need to see new things and have new experiences -- For better or worse.  These spirits have the most affinity with unrestricted travel magics as some people want to leave and explore while others just need to leave.  In exchange for enabling this rapid travel, the traveller must make a suitable offering.

In contrast, a forest spirit may hold just as strong a dominion over an area, but has little interest in exploring new lands so long as their forest is safe.  This is why one generally can't entreat a forest spirit for a teleport out of the forest and back to town.

The key takeaway from this is that one has to bargain for passage as well as having the correct offering for that passage.  Not everyone has the power, skill, and knowledge to pull that off repeatedly.

**Spiritual Matters**

But the spirits themselves have a parallel society of a sort as well as Rules that they too have to follow.  Relevant to the question, the main rule is that one does not just teleport into another town spirit's domain unless invited as that would be the height of rudeness.

As such, it is easier (and safer) to negotiate for passage to a more uninhabited area of the lands, such as a clearing in the forest, than it is to another town directly.  Also make sure your destination is a less significant area as well

There is a reason everyone calls the place Bear Mountain as the last person to drop in found out.  Their fate was grizzly ...

Likewise, the spirits also have relationships with each other which can also affect how easy or hard it is to travel about swiftly.  Two spirits at each other's metaphoric throats may be tricky to navigate between.  Alternatively, it may be that you can go, but you will be forced to be a messenger slash negotiator for this conflict.  Depends on temperaments.

**The Spiritual Way**

The rest of the magic system can be extrapolated -- spirits are around us, and the flesh and blood races can entreat them for favours/spells/boons.

There aren't arcane circles that can compel a spirit to answer or to draw forth its power to use later, or a specific formula of what to trade for what favour.  It's about relationships and what one is willing to do for the favour of something.  It's about keeping your promises and bargaining in good faith while being the kind of persons spirits would like to entreat with.

Sometimes, this is easy and sometimes it is not.  Such are the fickle ways of spirits.

It's a softer system as far as magics go, but that also means that you can be more in control of what is available.

The talent as whole is rare because while some have enough power, the may not have the temperament to actually deal properly with the spirits.  Meanwhile others don't have the power but know how to bargain so they are very good at getting little things.

Very rare is the person that is interesting enough to gain the consistent attention of the greater spirits and can safely entreat with them.  It may be a bit of a running question as to why somebody in this small group can do it.

**Pre-modern Societies**

To bring up a point directly about pre-modern societies, most people that can do this get small advantages -- hair that always behaves (when it needs to), a forge that holds a steady heat better, etc.

A blessing by one of the greater or greatest spirits might indicate a favoured person or bloodline to rule (see the pharaoh), but a blessing alone does not grant power to enforce one's rule.  One still needs to uphold the deal make to receive that blessing.

But no matter the world, there will still be complaints about bad copper.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the colonization, I think that you can set some rules:

- You have to physically touch a traveler in order to move with him/her. This means that you cannot move more than a dozen people a time (and the travel preparation would look like a Twister game...). Considering that travelers are rare and maybe need some time to recover, you cannot move an army to another country
- Also, some materials cannot be moved: for instance [cold iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_in_folklore#Cold_iron) prevents magic (which rules out some of the better weapons available)
- About the travel rules, the reason why people leave from cities and arrive in the wilderness could be more of a kind of statistical problem: it is possible to enter the travel dimension only from particular buildings, while you can exit everywhere. The problem is that if you go to a far land, you have no idea of where exactly you would exit, you would basically reach a random location in the region where you want to go. This means that it is statistically a lot more likely to find a wild place rather than a city (I presume there is not a lot of urbanization). This is made even worse by the lack of reliable maps (which would need some "old fashion" travel to be made precise enough).

Answer (score 0):

Your initial conditions make this somewhat difficult to answer. I can provide a rough framework, but you'll need quite a bit of work to tie it/upgrade into an internally-consistent, world-scale system. Also remember: in fictional worlds, if someone *really* wants to bend or trick the rules, they can.

1. Sending people from "civilized" places to anywhere else, but not the other way around: this necessitates a **technology cost** on this form of travel, for example

   - Powerful magical artefacts, that require research and high-quality materials to make;
   - Complex rituals, that require deep understanding of magic, lot of people, strict protocols, etc. to execute.
2. For the invading armies problem, the nature of the underlying magic must impose **quantity** and **time** limits on transport, for example:

   - The mass that can be transported in a single instance is limited;
   - The number of souls that can be transported in a single instance is limited;
   - The recharge rate of the method is sufficiently slow to prevent rapid repeated dispatches to the same destination;
   - The method requires alignment in the time dimension, e.g. it only works at high noon or midnight or the equinoces, etc.

Nonetheless, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to do something about the technology gap. No need for an invading army, when a small elite force with overwhelming technological (magical) advantage can beat whole communities into submission. Fear goes a long way here, and there will always be some locals, who'll collaborate with the invaders.

3. The generally low-magic setting requirement complicates things a lot:

   - You could use the technology gap to your advantage, i.e. there is magic, but most cultures can only use it in rudimentary forms. I think this would lead to something of a magical analogue of european countries trying to colonize the rest of the world.
   - You could go Harry Potter-style, so that magic is a rather rare talent, and magical communities are isolated, secretive, and limited in number and population.
   - For an even lower-magic setting, travel could be one of the very few forms of magic that people can use. For example, piggybacking on some natural-magic phenomenon, that provides both the *power* and *movement* aspect of the method, instead of free manipulation of magical energies.

To sum it up, your question is not an easy one, and a lot of it depends on the properties of the underlying magic system. That is too broad a topic for this site, so you need to work out the details yourself. Be prepared that it will take some work, and I believe that quite a few iterations, before you can achieve a sufficient level of internal consistency. Of course, *sufficient* is yours to define here :)